# getting rid of Scrapy - Amazon S3 log messages

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-s3, scrapy

My spider produces tons of log messages like this one:

```
2017-09-21 21:54:30 [botocore.vendored.requests.packages.urllib3.connectionpool] INFO: Starting new HTTPS connection (250): s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com
```

In `settings.py` my logging level is set to

```
LOG_LEVEL = 'INFO'
```

I've set the logging level for `urllib3` here:

```
class ExampleSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "example" 

    def __init__(self):
        self.domain = 'http://www.example.com'
        self.user_agent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.6; rv:10.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/10.0"
        logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
        logging.getLogger('requests').setLevel(logging.WARNING)
        logging.getLogger("urllib3").setLevel(logging.WARNING)
```

Why am I still getting the messages?

Answer (score 0):

You print the active loggers using

```
import logging
for key in logging.Logger.manager.loggerDict:
    print(key)
```

And then do something like

```
logging.getLogger('botocore.vendored.requests.packages.urllib3.connectionpool').setLevel(logging.NOTSET)
```